# create an array of matrix in python

Tags: python, arrays, matrix

I would like create an array of matrix in python, without use numpy. 
My array is a global variable:

```
file_data= []
```

And this is my matrix inside a function:

```
ncols = 4
nrows = 200000
matrix = [[0] * ncols for i in range(nrows)]
```

after I fill the matrix and try to assign the matrix at the array:

```
file_data[ff]=matrix
```

But I obtain this error:

```
    file_data[ff]=matrix
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

Could someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Your `file_data` is an empty list, and therefore accessing `file_data[ff]` result in `index out of range`, whatever your `ff` is. To fix this, you can do `file_data.append(matrix)`.